# Syntax Error in ArcGIS Field Calculator

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

I got a tiny script in ArcGIS which creates a hyperlink.

My code:

```
def Befahrung(value1, value2):
    if value1 is '':
        return ''
    else:
        return "G:\\Example\\" + str(value1) + "\\File_" + str(value2) + ".pdf"
```

The error (only when `!Bezeichnun!` contains a special character):

```
ERROR 000539: Error running expression: Befahrung(u" ",u"1155Mönch1")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<expression>", line 1 in <module>
  File "<string>", line 5 in Befahrung
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf6' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

`!Bezeichnun!` and `!Auftrag!` are both strings. It works very well until `!Bezeichnun!` contains a special character. I can't change the characters, I need to save them.

What do I have to change?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20)

Comment: You may should consider gis.stackexchange for that type of question

Comment: gis.stackexchange told me to consider stackoverflow

Comment: Dropping the hot potato

Comment: @Stophface Troubleshooting at GIS SE showed that this happens even when ArcGIS, its Field Calculator and ArcPy are not in the loop: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111416/python-ascii-codec-synthax-question-in-field-calculator  I think the asker should post their pure Python/IDLE test code here to illustrate that.

Comment: Make sure you use `if value1 == ''` instead of `if value1 is ''`. ArcGIS stores everything as unicode, and `u'' is ''` returns `False`.

Answer (score 2):

In `Befahrung`, you convert a string (Unicode in this case) to ASCII:

```
str(value1);
str(value2);
```

cannot work if `value1` or `value2` contain non-ASCII characters. You want to use

```
unicode(value1)
```

or better, use string formatting:

```
return u"G:\\Example\\{}\\File_{}.pdf".format(value1, value2)
```

(works in Python 2.7 and above)

Comment: If i try to use string formatting i get:

ERROR 000539: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal (<expression>, line 1)
Fehler beim Ausführen von (Feld füllen mit Verlinkung).

Comment: I assume you correctly used the double quotes around your format string ? That is `u"..."` and not `u"...''` for example. The error says your code contains a string which is not ended. (eg. `"hello`)

Comment: Wow, that's strange. This works in a Python 2.7 interpreter (that is formatting with Unicode arguments).

Comment: @SteveK As far as I know the ArcGIS Field Calculator is not quite a "pure" Python interpreter so there is a slight possibility that something that works in a Python 2.7 interpreter could throw an error there but at [GIS Stack Exchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111416/python-ascii-codec-synthax-question-in-field-calculator) we asked if the error was showing up in IDLE too and the answer was "yes".

Comment: Does it still not work if you use `u"G:\\Example\\{0}\\File_{1}.pdf".format(value1, value2)` (note the `0` and `1`) and the "PYTHON_9.3" interpreter?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend reading the [Python Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html). The error can be distilled to

```
>>> str(u"1155Mönch1")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf6' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

If you know what character encoding you need (e.g., UTF-8), you can encode it like

```
value1.encode('utf-8')
```